# Is there any alternative to Constant in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna, constants, kinect

I am creating a program using Microsoft XNA and Kinect. I want to get the width of a Skeleton. I have Skeleton Right and Left hand Points. I subtract them and get the Width of Skeleton. I want to store this Value in a constant so that it wont change if Skeleton moves anywhere.

I have written the following code but its giving me the following error message. Kindly tell me any alternative or  guide me how to use constant

```
Joint hand = skl.Joints[JointType.HandRight];
DepthImagePoint rightShoulderPt = sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint(rightShoulder.Position, DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30);

DepthImagePoint leftShoulderPt = sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint(leftShoulder.Position, DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30);
```

**EDIT**
//e.g
//These values will be continuously changing based on Skeleton Position. I want to freeze //these points and store them in some variable.

rightShoulderPt.X= 200;
leftShoulderPt.X = 450;

```
const float totalWidth = rightShoulderPt.X - leftShoulderPt.X;
```

> Error 1   The expression being assigned to 'totalWidth' must be constant

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just never change the value. The `constant` keyword is meant for compile-time constants, not runtime!

You could use `readonly` and assign this value in the constructor. Other than that, I don't think there's a specific keyword for your situation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Would `readonly` change the variable value or not?

Comment: Readonly is a keyword. All it does, is ensure you can only assign this variable in the constructor. After that, it can not be modified again.

Comment: +1. @user3480644 `readonly` is modifier that limits when you can change to value... not sure what your comment mean: "readonly change the variable or not" (see MSDN link provided by Robert Harvey's answer for details).

Comment: but i want to assign the values in some other method..Its not the Constructor?

Comment: @user3480644: Then it's not a constant, and it's not read only.  Just never change the value.

Comment: I think you'll have to show more of your code if we are to help here. Is this variable a field in a class? If so, making it `readonly` would ensure that you can only assign to it in the class constructor. If you want to assign to it after that, you can not use `readonly` or `constant`. Is there a problem with just "not changing" the value yourself? It won't change if the skeleton moves, unless you explicitly change it.

Comment: Its a Kinect Based application, I have developed it in XNA, XNA has an update method which runs 24 times in a second, and it records Skeleton Position. Its value is continuously changing. I want to grab the first value and store it in a variable that won't change....I have updated my Question Kindly check it.

Comment: Just declare a field and assign this value once. Perhaps make it a `Nullable<float>` or check if it's not equal to 0.0. In your update loop, only assign it if it has not been done before. Remember, just because XNA provides you with this data, does not mean you have to overwrite your own derived values every time.

Answer (score 2):

`readonly` allows you to set the value in the constructor, but forbids any further changes.

> The readonly keyword is a modifier that you can use on fields. When a
>   field declaration includes a readonly modifier, assignments to the
>   fields introduced by the declaration can only occur as part of the
>   declaration or in a constructor in the same class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx